# Conflict Serialize explanations

Tags: database

I'm trying to understand exactly how to determine if a schedule is Conflict Serializable

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We can determine whether a history is conflict-serializable by analyzing a graph derived from the history called a *serialization graph*.

Let `H` be a history over `T = \{ T_1, T_2, \ldots, T_n \}`. The serialization graph (SG) for `H`, denoted `SG(H)`, is a directed graph whose nodes are the transactions in `T` that are committed in `H` and whose edges are all `T_i \to T_j` (`i \neq j`) such that one of `T_i`'s operations precedes and conflicts with one of `T_j`'s operations in `H`.

Each edge `T_i \to T_j`, in `SC(H)` means that at least one of `T_i`'s operations precedes and  conflicts with one of `T_j`'s. This suggests that `T_i` should precede `T_j` in any serial history that  is equivalent to `H`. If we can find a serial history, `H_s`, consistent with all edges in  `SG(H)`,  then `H_s` is conflict-equivalent to `H` and so `H` is conflict-serializable. We can do this as long as `SG(H)` is acyclic.

Formally, we have the fundamental theorem of (conflict-)serializability theory:

> A history `H` is conflict-serializable if and only if `SG(H)` is acyclic.

**Note:** For the details, please refer to [Page 33 in Chapter 2 of Philip A. Bernstein et al.](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/philbe/chapter2.pdf).